# Watch emulator size of phone, how to resize?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator, wear-os

Testing an Android wear watch app and the emulator is size of phone not a watch. 
How please can I change this?

These are my emulator settings
[image: These are my emulator settings]

This is what it looks like
[image: This is what it looks like]

Comment: Better use genymotion emulators, they are faster and can be resized even in runtime

Comment: I think the image you downloaded is not of android wear, can you confirm ?

Comment: It is a phone by the look of it. But it's what I get when choosing "Android wear square". So it should be a wear device. However as you can see it appears to be a phone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved: In short it was the skin that was set wrong.

Changed it in emulator advance settings. Annoying though because when you set up a wear emulator you would hare thought it naturally give you a wear skin, but no!